# What is the meaning of $0 in the Bash shell

Tags: bash

From Bash Manual

> `$0` Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at
>   shell initialization.
>
> If Bash is invoked with a file of commands (see Section 3.8 [Shell
>   Scripts], page 39), `$0` is set to the name of that file.
>
> If Bash is started with the `-c` option (see Section 6.1 [Invoking
>   Bash], page 80), then `$0` is set to the first argument after the
>   string to be executed, if one is present.
>
> **Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as given by argument zero.**

I understand the first two cases, but not the last one.
What do "otherwise" and "the filename used to invoke Bash" mean specifically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bash can be invoked in various ways, including directly using its executable (`/bin/bash`) or a link to it; this is often the case with `/bin/sh`. "Otherwise" covers this case, and the filename used to invoke Bash is just that — `bash`, `sh`, `/bin/sh` etc.

Try it and you'll see: `bash` then `echo $0` prints `bash`, `/bin/bash` then `echo $0` prints `/bin/bash`, etc.

Arguably this also covers shebangs but perhaps that's the first case.